# What does Total Allocation mean in the JFR result as viewed in JDK Mission Control?

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, allocation, jfr, jmc

Im having a weird scenario where Im attempting to determine the root cause for some process restarts. We collected JFR for a period and I see that the heap does not grow over time. The maximum size of the heap remains below 2 GiB at all times.

However, I see that the total allocation for a class `byte[]` is around 180+ GiB while the total physical memory is just 128 GB. The total allocation percentage for the same class is 58.4%. However the max live size is 171 MiB.

Also, I see that the "Used Size" is also quite high(125 GiB). And I see this message in the automated analysis section of the JFR profile:

```
The maximum amount of used memory was 99.7 % of the physical memory available.
The maximum amount of memory used was 125 GiB. This is 99.7 % of the 126 GiB of physical memory available. Having little free memory may lead to swapping, which is very expensive. To avoid this, either decrease the memory usage or increase the amount of available memory.
```

Im very confused here. Does total allocation mean the amount of data in the physical memory? Or is it just the total amount of memory that was allocated but has since then been garbage collected?

Answer (score 0):

The message was generated by "Low on Physical Memory" rule. You can verify that's the rule by looking at the [message](https://github.com/openjdk/jmc/blob/master/core/org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.jdk/src/main/resources/org/openjdk/jmc/flightrecorder/rules/jdk/messages/internal/messages.properties) text and [implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jmc/blob/master/core/org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.jdk/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmc/flightrecorder/rules/jdk/memory/LowOnPhysicalMemoryRule.java).

From what I can see, it uses the OS_MEMORY_SUMMARY event and not events related to object allocation.

Comment: So does this mean the "Total Allocation" is not tied to the amount of data that is present in the physical memory?

Comment: The two measurements are "Total amount of physical memory available to OS" and "Total amount of physical memory in use".

Comment: Sorry which of the above correspond to "Total Allocation"?

Comment: Those describe physical memory. "Total Allocation" refers to object allocation, i.e. new byte[1000]. If some of the objects are garbage collected, the total allocation number may become larger than the number displayed for physical memory.

Comment: So if we see an abnormally high count for a certain class in Total Allocation, could that be indicative of a memory leak? Or is it just that a certain class has a lot of instances which are allocated and deallocated(via Garbage collection) and does not severely impact physical memory?

Comment: It's unlikely to be a memory leak. It's just a lot of object allocations, which are collected by the GC.